# How to get google user account email in Android device with appium

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I am testing an Android app which shows me a dialog with a google account email taken from Android OS as one of its text fields.

I can not find how Appium can help me with it, only if I will navigate from Android settings window to accounts window.

Any suggestions how can I get the default google user account email from Android OS in the Appium environment?

Eclipse + Java\ 
Appium desktop client - 1.6.5
real device nexus5 api 23